# parallella fpga : how to give an interrupt from pl to arm ps

Tags: arm, interrupt, fpga, zynq, parallella

I successfully implemented an "[accelerator in 15 minutes]"[1](https://www.parallella.org/2016/01/21/creating-an-fpga-accelerator-in-15-minutes/) on parallella board. Now I need to send an interrupt from pl to ps. So I connected it to IRQ_F2P of Zynq processing system.

**Now, how can I get this interrupt in arm processor?**

Usual interrupt example using "XILINX SDK" tool which uses a JTAG. But in parallella , I don't have a JTAG. (I am coping the program to SD card and execute it from SD card using Ubuntu). So any suggestions are most welcome.

So for parallella, I tried to use the Xilinx SDK, but the header files are creating an error..
My one more doubt is **"Is it possible to create a bsp using sdk tool and copy it into sd card and then make it run on parallella board. Will it work ?**
If not, how do we get this interrupt in arm processor, because all example uses Xilinx header files like "xparameters.h, xil_printf.h, xcugic.h, etc" and these are connected to many other Xilinx functions.

Comment: What kind of error are you getting? If you want to get the interrupt and you are using Ubuntu (Linux), you will have to create a driver to register the interrupt. You will need the IRQ number, and request_irq() function.

Comment: In SDK, there are Xilinx libraries, but inside the SD card(Ubuntu running on it), there is no Xilinx library. So I can't compile it. Is there any other way to do it? I have IRQ number. Do I need to write "request_irq()" or will ARM provides it. And thanks for the reply :)

Comment: I cannot give much details about the libraries. But you can probably copy paste them and use them in the Ubuntu if they are compatible.
request_irq is a kernel function https://www.fsl.cs.sunysb.edu/kernel-api/re667.html that you can use to register an interrupt inside a driver linux